# How to Update a document by replacing it with a new document in a collection of mongoDB

Tags: objective-c, mongodb, objcmongodb

I am using ObjCMongoDB as a cocoa wrapper for accessing mongoDB. I am facing difficulty in a scenario where I have to find and replace a document with a new document. Can any one help me by pointing out the code/API of ObjCMongoDB to use.

For example:

```
{
"_id" : { "$oid" : "51de4ed737965b2d233f4862"} ,
"milestone" : "Application 7.1 release" ,
"pendingtasklist" : [ task1 , task2 , task3]
}
```

here I have to **replace** pendingtasklist with new list and result should be

```
{
"_id" : { "$oid" : "51de4ed737965b2d233f4862"} ,
"milestone" : "Application 7.1 release" ,
"someotherlist" : [ task12 , task33 , task32]
}
```

I have attached the code I am using to achieve this, but without success

```
NSError *connectionError = nil;
MongoConnection *dbConn = [MongoConnection connectionForServer:@"127.0.0.1:27017" error:&connectionError];


MongoDBCollection *collection = [dbConn collectionWithName:@"mydb.milestones"];

MongoKeyedPredicate *predicate = [MongoKeyedPredicate predicate];
[predicate keyPath:@"milestone" matches:@"Application 7.1 release"];

MongoUpdateRequest *updateReq = [MongoUpdateRequest updateRequestWithPredicate:predicate  firstMatchOnly:YES];
NSDictionary *milestoneDict = @{@"problemlist": @[@"12345",@"112244",@"55543",@"009009"],@"milestone":@"Application 7.1 release"};
[updateReq replaceDocumentWithDictionary:milestoneDict];

BOOL result = [collection updateWithRequest:updateReq error:&connectionError];
```

Before my collection will have documents like this:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "51de4ed737965b2d233f4862"} , "milestone" : "Application 7.1 Release" , "problemlist" : [ 12345 , 112244 , 55543]}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "51de4ed737965b2d233f4864"} , "milestone" : "Application 7.1 UAT" ,  "problemlist" : [ 33545 , 7654 , 8767]}
```

Comment: The above code works perfectly, there was a extra space in the string while creating the predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value were staying the same, you would just rename the key:

- `-[MongoUpdateRequest keyPath:renameToKey:`]

But since the values are changing, you should just unset the old key and set the new one.

- `-[MongoUpdateRequest unsetValueForKeyPath:]`
- `-[MongoUpdateRequest keyPath:setValue:]`

As I mentioned above you can do this with a single update request.

Comment: The string for milestone doesn't match your sample data, which has an extra space before Release. To add values to an array, use -arrayForKeyPath:appendValuesFromArray: instead. What exactly is happening? What are the values of result, and of connectionError?

Comment: Basically in a my collection, I have lot of documents which has lot of key:values. In update I dont want to check each field in a document and write query to update the document. Instead I want to replace the document with a updated document which might have some new key:value added or deleted. Hope I am clear this time :) And the BOOL result will be YES but the DB is not getting updated.

Comment: Found it! as u said there was a typo with my string and db document.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Is ObjCMongoDB thread safe? I have like 200 asynchronous operations executing and all of them has DB Insert/Update as their last task. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to rename a field, you need to remove the old one, and add the new one. In this case, you would have to run two separate queries for this.

Comment: First sentence yes; second sentence no. In Mongo, you can make multiple changes to a document with a single update request.